# helm - programmatically override subchart values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm writing a helm chart that uses the [stable/redis](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis) chart as a subchart.

I need to override the storage class name used for both microservices within my chart, and within the redis chart.

I'm using helm 2.12.3

I would like to be able to specify redis.master.persistence.storageClass in terms of a template, like so

```
storage:
  storageClasses:
    name: azurefile

redis:
  usePassword: false
  master:
    persistence:
      storageClass: {{ $.Values.storage.storageClasses.name }}
```

Except, as I understand, templates aren't supported within values.yaml

As this is a public chart, I'm not able to modify it to depend on a global value as described here in [the documentation](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md)

I considered using `{{ $.Values.redis.master.persistence.storageClass }}` elsewhere in my chart rather than `{{ $.Values.storage.storageClasses.name }}`, but this would:

- Not hide the complexity of the dependencies of my chart
- Not scale if I was to add yet another subchart dependency

In my values.yaml file I have:

```
storage:
  storageClasses:
    name: azurefile

redis:
  master:
    persistence:
      storageClass: azurefile
```

I would like to specify a single value in values.yaml that can be overwritten at chart deploy time.

e.g. like this

```
helm install --set storage.storageClasses.name=foo mychart
```

rather than

```
helm install --set storage.storageClasses.name=foo --set redis.master.persistence.storageClass mychart
```

Comment: Have you considered making azureFile (required storageClass) a default storageClass ?

Comment: This would solve my immediate problem, but I'm more interested in how to solve this in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly mentioned, helm value files are plain yaml files which cannot contain any templates. For your use case, you'd need to use a templating system for your values files also which basically means you are also generating your value files on the go. I'd suggest taking a look at [helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile). This lets you share values file across multiple charts and application environments.