# How to pass dynamic data to helm subchart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the `mongodb` helm chart and the `mongo-express` one. `mongodb` generates the name depending on my release name, so it is dynamic. The `mongodb` service name will be something like `my-release-mongodb`.

`mongo-express` requires to pass `mongodbServer` - the location at which the `mongodb` can be reached. How can I provide this value to `mongo-express` if it is generated and can change depending on the release name?

Comment: You may have to do some kind of scripting to get the service name of `mongodb` and when you run `helm install` for `mongo-express` use `--set serviceName=<value_from_script>`.

Comment: Ok I see. Is that not a common issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helm doesn't directly have this ability.  (See also [helm - programmatically override subchart values.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425688/helm-programmatically-override-subchart-values-yaml).)  It has a couple of ways to [propagate configured values from a subchart to a parent](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#importing-child-values-via-dependencies) but not to use computed values, or to send these values to a sibling chart.

In the particular case of Services created by a subchart, I've generally considered the Service name as part of the chart's "API": you know the Service will be named `{{ .Release.Name }}-mongodb` and you just have to hard-code that in the consuming chart.

If you're launching this under a single "umbrella" chart, this is a little more straightforward.  Both parts have the same release name, so you can construct the service name the same way.  (Umbrella charts have other limitations – if you have multiple services that each should have an independent MongoDB installation, Helm will only deploy the database once for the whole umbrella chart – but you can still hit this same problem making HTTP calls between microservices.)

If they're totally separate installations, you may need to pick the release name yourself and pass it in as a value.

```sh
helm install thedb ./mongodb
helm install theapp ./mongo-express --set serviceName=thedb-mongodb
```

This also a place where a still higher-level tool like [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) or [Helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman) can come in handy, since that would let you specify these parameters in a fixed file.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Could you elaborate a bit on the umbrella part? I have everything in one chart as you say, and `mongodb` and `mongo-express` are direct dependencies of that chart. How does that help me exactly?

Comment: `.Release.Name` is the same in the parent chart and all of the subcharts, so you can specify `{{ .Release.Name }}-mongodb` in the client without having to know the release name up front.

Comment: Ah ok yes. For reference, here is the issue I found in the subject https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2133